# Why does my DVD drive spin up every minute or so, spin down, and repeat (new Dell Studio 15 with Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, laptop, optical-drive, spinup

We have just got a new Dell Studio 15 laptop running Windows 7 home premium with slot load DVD drive. If there is a DVD drive in the drive, every minute or so, the drive will spin up, make a couple of noises like it is reading something and then spin down.

I think this is ruining battery life.

There is no software running that is obviously accessing the drive.

Any ideas to what it could be? Are there any tools I could use to try and identify the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is realted to Dell's DataSafe Backup software.  I just uninstalled it and the spin ups went away. You can test it by stopping the process "STService.exe".  If the spin ups go away then you know it is the same software issue with your laptop.